# Is there an equivalent Python function similar to complete.cases in R

Tags: python, pandas

I am removing a number of records in a pandas data frame which contains diverse combinations of NaN in the 4-columns frame. I have created a function called complete_cases to provide indexes of rows which met the following condition: all columns in the row are NaN.

I have tried this function below:

```py
def complete_cases(dataframe):
    indx = []
    indx = [x for x in list(dataframe.index) \
            if dataframe.loc[x, :].isna().sum() == 
            len(dataframe.columns)]
    return indx
```

I am wondering should this is optimal enough or there is a better way to do this.

Comment: The backslash is not required inside brackets.

Comment: Simply use `dropna`. If you want it more explicit like above, any is better than sum for this case `dataframe[~dataframe.isna().any(axis=1)]`

Comment: @maow Thanks but I want to delete only records with full NaN values, not partially NaN's.

Comment: Following @maow, you can use `.all()` then

Comment: Thanks @Mayeulsgc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend to use [`loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html), [`notna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.notna.html), and [`all`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.all.html) with `'columns'` axis, like this:

```py
df.loc[df.notna().all(axis='columns')]
```

This way you'll filter only the results like the `complete.cases` in R.

Answer (score 15):

Absolutely. All you need to do is

```
df.dropna(axis = 0, how = 'any', inplace = True)
```

This will remove all rows that have at least one missing value, and updates the data frame "inplace".

Comment: This is the same as df<-df[complete.cases(df),] but it is not the same as complete.cases(...).

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution:

Count the number of columns with "NA" creating a column to save it

Based on this new column, filter the rows of the data frame as you wish

Remove the (now) unnecessary column

It is possible to do it with a lambda function. For example, if you want to remove rows that have 10 "NA" values:

```
df['count'] = df.apply(lambda x: 0 if x.isna().sum() == 10 else 1, axis=1)
df = df[df.count != 0]
del df['count']
```